# gvim: yank lines between buffers

Tags: vim

I try to copy the lines 7,11 from buffer 2 to my buffer 3 without leaving buffer 3. Is it possible to do that with a simple command?

Usually I go to B2, yank the lines come back to B3 and paste them. I will be interest to do that using range but I do not succeed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ingo Karkat and Meninx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the `getbufline()` function that allows you to obtain lines from another buffer. You can `:put` that into the current buffer via the *expression register*:

```
:put =getbufline(2, 7, 11)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using unix you can use this command:

```
 :r! sed -n 7,11p #2
```

Comment: You can see it as a warning for modified buffer (see the glass as half full) ;). Thanks for the note !